# Tengo esta vista en MYSQL, y da como resultado aprox 7000 registro, quisiera ingresar esos resultado en otra tabla

Tags: mysql, select, insert

Tengo esta vista en MYSQL y da como resultado 7.000 registros, quisera que esos resultados se inserten en otra tabla. ¿Cómo podria hacer eso?.

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `glpi_redondos`.`vista_indicador_tickets` AS
    SELECT 
        `tk`.`id` AS `Ticket_ID`,
        `tk`.`name` AS `Nombre_Ticket`,
        (CASE
            WHEN (`tk`.`type` = 1) THEN 'Incidente'
            ELSE 'Solicitud'
        END) AS `Tipo_Ticket`,
        `tk`.`date` AS `Fecha_Ticket`,
        `tk`.`closedate` AS `Fecha_Cierre_Ticket`,
        `tk`.`solvedate` AS `Fecha_Solucion_Ticket`,
        `tk`.`status` AS `status`,
        (CASE
            WHEN (`tk`.`status` = 1) THEN '1-Nuevos'
            WHEN (`tk`.`status` = 2) THEN '2-En curso (asignada)'
            WHEN (`tk`.`status` = 3) THEN '3-En curso (planificada)'
            WHEN (`tk`.`status` = 4) THEN '4-En espera'
            WHEN (`tk`.`status` = 5) THEN '5-Resuelto'
            WHEN (`tk`.`status` = 6) THEN '6-Cerrado'
        END) AS `Descripcion_Status`,
        `rq`.`name` AS `Medio_De_Requerimiento`,
        `ic`.`completename` AS `Categoria_ITIL`,
        `u`.`name` AS `Username_Usuario_Solicitante`,
        `u`.`firstname` AS `Nombres_Usuario_Solicitante`,
        `u`.`realname` AS `Apellidos_Usuario_Solicitante`,
        `l`.`name` AS `Nombre_Ubicacion`,
        `u`.`registration_number` AS `DNI_Usuario`,
        `ut`.`name` AS `Nombre_Area`,
        `tk`.`urgency` AS `Nivel_Urgencia`,
        (CASE
            WHEN (`tk`.`urgency` = 1) THEN 'Muy Bajo'
            WHEN (`tk`.`urgency` = 2) THEN 'Bajo'
            WHEN (`tk`.`urgency` = 3) THEN 'Media'
            WHEN (`tk`.`urgency` = 4) THEN 'Alta'
            WHEN (`tk`.`urgency` = 5) THEN 'Muy Alta'
        END) AS `Descripcion_Urgencia`,
        `tk`.`impact` AS `Nivel_Impacto`,
        (CASE
            WHEN (`tk`.`impact` = 1) THEN 'Muy Bajo'
            WHEN (`tk`.`impact` = 2) THEN 'Bajo'
            WHEN (`tk`.`impact` = 3) THEN 'Media'
            WHEN (`tk`.`impact` = 4) THEN 'Alta'
            WHEN (`tk`.`impact` = 5) THEN 'Muy Alta'
        END) AS `Descripcion_Impacto`,
        `tk`.`priority` AS `Nivel_Prioridad`,
        (CASE
            WHEN (`tk`.`priority` = 1) THEN 'Muy Bajo'
            WHEN (`tk`.`priority` = 2) THEN 'Bajo'
            WHEN (`tk`.`priority` = 3) THEN 'Media'
            WHEN (`tk`.`priority` = 4) THEN 'Alta'
            WHEN (`tk`.`priority` = 5) THEN 'Muy Alta'
        END) AS `Descripcion_Prioridad`,
        `tk`.`internal_time_to_own` AS `Tiempo_Inicio_Atencion`,
        `tk`.`internal_time_to_resolve` AS `Tiempo_Termino_Atencion`,
        (SELECT 
                `glpi_redondos`.`glpi_users`.`name`
            FROM
                `glpi_redondos`.`glpi_users`
            WHERE
                (`glpi_redondos`.`glpi_users`.`id` = `tku`.`users_id`)) AS `Username_Usuario_Asignado`,
        (SELECT 
                `glpi_redondos`.`glpi_users`.`realname`
            FROM
                `glpi_redondos`.`glpi_users`
            WHERE
                (`glpi_redondos`.`glpi_users`.`id` = `tku`.`users_id`)) AS `Apellidos_Usuario_Asignado`,
        (SELECT 
                `glpi_redondos`.`glpi_users`.`firstname`
            FROM
                `glpi_redondos`.`glpi_users`
            WHERE
                (`glpi_redondos`.`glpi_users`.`id` = `tku`.`users_id`)) AS `Nombres_Usuario_Asignado`,
        `ts`.`satisfaction` AS `Nivel_Satisfaccion`,
        `ts`.`comment` AS `Comentario_Satisfaccion`
    FROM
        (((((((`glpi_redondos`.`glpi_tickets` `tk`
        LEFT JOIN `glpi_redondos`.`glpi_requesttypes` `rq` ON ((`tk`.`requesttypes_id` = `rq`.`id`)))
        LEFT JOIN `glpi_redondos`.`glpi_itilcategories` `ic` ON ((`tk`.`itilcategories_id` = `ic`.`id`)))
        LEFT JOIN `glpi_redondos`.`glpi_users` `u` ON ((`tk`.`users_id_recipient` = `u`.`id`)))
        LEFT JOIN `glpi_redondos`.`glpi_locations` `l` ON ((`u`.`locations_id` = `l`.`id`)))
        LEFT JOIN `glpi_redondos`.`glpi_usertitles` `ut` ON ((`ut`.`id` = `u`.`usertitles_id`)))
        LEFT JOIN `glpi_redondos`.`glpi_tickets_users` `tku` ON (((`tk`.`id` = `tku`.`tickets_id`)
            AND (`tku`.`type` = 2))))
        LEFT JOIN `glpi_redondos`.`glpi_ticketsatisfactions` `ts` ON ((`tk`.`id` = `ts`.`tickets_id`)))
    WHERE
        (`tk`.`is_deleted` = 0)
```

---

Answer (score 4):

Simplemente haz un select sobre tu vista ya creada y crea la tabla con esos resultados:

```
CREATE TABLE nombre_tabla AS
    (SELECT * FROM nombre_vista);
```

Referencia: [Easy 'create table from view' syntax in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241922/easy-create-table-from-view-syntax-in-mysql)

Comment: CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `glpi_redondos`.`vista_indicador_tickets` AS
    CREATE TABLE GuardarTickets(SELECT 
        `tk`.`id` AS `Ticket_ID`,
        `tk`.`name` AS `Nombre_Ticket`,
        (CASE
            WHEN (`tk`.`type` = 1) THEN 'Incidente'
            ELSE 'Solicitud' ); Algo asi

Comment: Si lo que quieres es insertar todos los datos de la vista **`glpi_redondos`.`vista_indicador_tickets`** en una nueva tabla, con este código debería generarte esa nueva tabla con todos los registros de la vista:

CREATE TABLE nombre_tabla AS
    (SELECT * FROM `glpi_redondos`.`vista_indicador_tickets` );